# Перемещение объектов в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

допустим у меня есть 4 пути с 2 точками (Point 1 и Point 2).

есть объект меж этих двух точке который сидит по этой формуле

```
Box.position = Vector2.Lerp(points[point].position, points[point + 1].position, T);
```

есть значение от 0 до 1 которое привязано к Lerp , скорость Speed

```
[Range(0,1)]
public float T;
public float speed;
```

вопрос . как определить какое число я должен прибавить к T , чтобы все кубы шли с одной скорость ? и не важно какой длинны путь.

Comment: Для первого `T`, для второго `T / 2`, для третьего `T / 3`, для четвертого `T / 4`.

Comment: Задачка для 5го класса, дне начинают учить дроби с примеры типа машина с скоростью V проехала дистанцию L, за какое время она проехала? Боюсь ваше проблему не решить на Stack.

Comment: и чем вы мне помогли ?
Stanislav Volodarskiy есть одна маленькая проблема. ты не прочел , что надо для любого расстояния.
Yaroslav ну так скажи что делать , если это так легко .

Answer (score 0):

Если целью является перемещение объектов с одинаковой скоростью. И использование Lerp не обязательно, то можно воспользоваться моей функцией. Но она перемещает, с помощью изменения позиции.

```
private IEnumerator Move(GameObject gameObjectToMove, Vector3 targetPosition, Vector3? startPosition = null, int speed = 10, Action OnMoved = null)
    {
        Transform transformOfGameObjectToMove = gameObjectToMove.transform;

        if (startPosition != null)
        {
            transformOfGameObjectToMove.position = (Vector3) startPosition;
        }
        
        while (true)
        {     
            if (targetPosition != transformOfGameObjectToMove.position)
            {
                LookAt(gameObjectToMove, targetPosition);
            
                float distanceToDestination = Vector2.Distance(transformOfGameObjectToMove.position, targetPosition);
            
                if (distanceToDestination > (Time.deltaTime * speed))
                {
                    transformOfGameObjectToMove.position += (targetPosition - transformOfGameObjectToMove.position).normalized * (speed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    transformOfGameObjectToMove.position = targetPosition;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                OnMoved?.Invoke();
                yield break;
            }
            
            void LookAt(GameObject gameObjectToRotate, Vector3 targetPosition)
            {
                //this code will point the object to the mouse
                // transform.right = _targetPosition - transform.position;
                Vector3 diff = targetPosition - transform.position;
                diff.Normalize();
            
                float rot_z = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                gameObjectToRotate.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rot_z - 90);
                //
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
        }
    }
```

Пример использования.

```
private void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(Move(gameObjectToMove : Box, targetPosition : points[point + 1].position, startPosition : points[point].position, speed: 15));
}
```